# how to always run gradle task B after task A

Tags: gradle, task

Anyone knows how to get B to always run after A even if I only use 'gradle A' on the command line?  My first thought was that I could use mustRunAfter, but that seems to require me to specify B on the command line.

```
task A << {
    println 'A'
}

task B << {
    println 'B'
}
```

Comment: task B << {  dependsOn A ...next line..your code here for task B... } or task B (dependsOn A) << { ...your code for task B comes here.. } or task B (dependsOn A) { ...your code for task B comes here.. }

Answer (score 4):

The (only) way to do so (not counting hacks) is `A finalizedBy B`. Note that this will run `B` even if `A` failed.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use **dependsOn** feature in Gradle task.

For ex: If you run "gradle ohohWorldTask", it'll always calls myHelloTask to echo "hello" first.

```
// Say hello
task myHelloTask() << {
   println "hello"
}


// Say world
//task ohohWorldTask( dependsOn: [ myHelloTask ] ) << {
//or - using the above you can specify multiple tasks comma separated within [ aTask, bTask, cTask ]

task ohohWorldTask( dependsOn: myHelloTask ) << {
  println "-- World!"
}
```

Comment: This will work if you run `gradle ohohWorldTask` but OP wants it to work if they just run `gradle myHelloTask`

Comment: that's why I said ohohWorldTask (as its name), in that case he can use doFirst { ... } within myHelloTask or A. Thanks for catching it.